# Definition of "deterministic coupling" [Villani]

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, optimal-transport

I'm currently reading through "Optimal transport, old and new" by Cédric Villani. In the first chapter, he defines a coupling of two probability spaces $(\mathcal{X},\mu)$ and $(\mathcal{Y},\nu)$ as a probability measure $\pi$ defined on $\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}$ such that $\pi$ admits $\mu$ and $\nu$ as marginals over $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ respectively.

This is fine, I understand it. However, he then goes on to define a special kind of coupling, a **deterministic** coupling of $(\mathcal{X},\mu)$ and $(\mathcal{Y},\nu)$ which satisfies:

1. There is a measurable function $T$ such that $\mathcal{Y} = T(\mathcal{X})$
2. $\pi =(Id,T)_\# \mu $ (where # denotes the pushforward measure).

Point number 2 is what confuses me. $\pi$ is defined over $\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}$, however for any subset $E$ of $\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}$, $(Id,T)_\# \mu (E) = \mu((Id,T)^{-1}(E))$ but $\mu$ is only defined over $\mathcal{X}$, so I'm not sure how $\mu((Id,T)^{-1}(E))$ makes sense? Also, I'm unsure how to interpret $(Id,T)^{-1}(E)$.

If anyone is familiar with the above terminology I would greatly appreciate some guidance.

Comment: This question was asked a long time ago. But do you have any idea how to prove the first condition in the book - that $\pi$ is concentrated on the graph of the measurable function $T$.

Comment: @almosteverywhere I think the answer is that the image of $(Id, T)$ in $\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}$ _is_ the graph of the measurable function $T$, so by definition the pushforward measure can only be supported on the graph (because the preimage of $(Id, T)$ of any measurable subset of $\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}$ disjoint from it is the empty set, and for any measure on $\mathcal{X}$ it's going to return $0$ for the empty set)

Answer (score 4):

The function $(Id,T):X\to X\times Y$ is given by $(Id,T)(x)=(Id(x),T(x))=(x,T(x))$. Now let $E\in\mathcal{X}\otimes\mathcal{Y}$. Then $$(Id,T)^{-1}(E)=\{x\in X:(Id,T)(x)\in E\}$$
$$=\{x\in X:(x,T(x))\in E\}.$$
If we can write $E=A\times B$ with $A\in\mathcal{X}$ and $B\in\mathcal{Y}$, we have

$$(Id,T)^{-1}(E)=\{x\in X:(x,T(x))\in A\times B\}$$

$$ =\{x\in X:x\in A\text{ and }T(x)\in B\}$$

$$ =\{x\in X:x\in A\text{ and }x\in T^{-1}(B)\}$$

$$ =A\cap T^{-1}(B). $$

A probability measure defined on $\mathcal{X}\otimes\mathcal{Y}$ is already determined by its values on "measurable rectangles" $A\times B$, so the last expression suffices already to specify this coupling.